# Which is the most secure way to connect to the office network from outside?

Tags: networking, security, vpn, remote-access

For working remotely, I am looking for the most secure way of logging-in to office network from outside.

Being a data center, the minute chance of vulnerability issues cannot accepted.

Is open VPN secure enough?

Any other new releases?

Kindly suggest the best and the safest option available.

Comment: Is your  virtual private network functionality built in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is open VPN secure enough?

Yes.

If you can try to ditch anything Windows and browser related when connecting. Those 2 are the main problems when talking security to a data center.

We use VPN through our Ubuntu server to our data center and not through Windows clients. So we need to log into our server 1st using a terminal session (putty) from a Windows desktop, set up the VPN from within our server and then we can use a terminal client to connect to the data center.

Comment: Rinzwind : So you are assuring that this is secure? Can I go for Open VPN or can you suggest any better release?

Comment: Yes. By the way: it is just as secure as any other VPN. OpenVPN uses OpenSSQL. But how secure your connection is is up to -you-. If you send passwords over mail for instance... the VPN can be as secure as it can be but you are possibly compromized at the moment you send the mail.

Comment: And to elaborate: for someone to get onto our data center they need access to a desktop at work (physical or remote), know to open putty. know the system password of our server, know the password to use to create the vpn and then need to know they need to "ssh" to the data center and then know the password at the data center.  Layer on layer on layer. And not one of them is stored, guessable by us and the passwords themself are changed every week during our weekly meeting. Not that the data we have on our data center is sensitive but it is our clients data so we are cautious  ;-)

Comment: I think this is enough to go on for on Open VPN.